# Single-spa is inserting microfrontend into both divs on a two microfrontend page

Tags: single-spa

I have a React application using Typescript, trying to load two microfrontends onto a single page at the same time.

I have verified both remoteEntry.js files are accessible and have loaded from the appropriate places and are different. When displaying one at a time they load in fine. When they are put on a combined page the same microfrontend gets displayed in both divs. The div ID's are unique on the target div's, and when I remove them single-spa will create two divs and still display the same MFE in both.

When inspecting the DOM I see the same module__container--id set for both sub div classes like it is literally putting the same microfrontend into both target divs.

Getting the loaded applications and statuses shows both with unique names and the status of mounted.

I was expecting these to load in correctly. On rare occasions the app will load in the second MFE into both divs instead of the first MFE.

Comment: Show code.  Are you using the layout engine or not?

Comment: I'm not using the layout engine, would that help? Unfortunately I can't show my project's code. I will try to recreate it in a POC fashion and will post the code.

Comment: I never use the layout engine, so my initial impression would be that it doesn't help.  It's just another way of doing things.  If you're not using layout engine, you must be using `registerApplication()` + pre-created DIV or similar elements with the special ID `single-spa-application:<MFE name>`.  Show those parts.